# how to draw a histogram in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: my data with name called as ranges_freq]

my data with name called as ranges_freq as below

```
    buckets     userid  
 0   10           730  
 1   50           435  
 2   100          150  
 3   500          314  
 4   1000         97  
 5   1001         244
```

I am able to draw a bar chart by using the below code but i am unable to draw a histogram for the same data.

```
>y = ranges_freq['userid']
 xlabels = ranges_freq['buckets']
 bar_width = 0.50
 x = np.arange(len(y))
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 ax.bar(x, y, width=bar_width)
 ax.set_xticks(x + (bar_width/2.0))
 ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
 ax.set_title('User Frequency by range')
 ax.set_xlabel('buckets')
 ax.set_ylabel('no.of.users')
 plt.show()
```

[image: this is how i got the image for bar chart]

so how can i draw the histogram for the samedata with same parmeters that i have used for the barchart
please help me how to draw the histogram in same way?

Comment: same as bar chart but with out spaces(histogram)

Answer (score 0):

So to remove the spaces in your bar chart, the only thing you need to do, is to set

```
bar_width = 1.0
```

Result:
[image]

But you have to understand that this *is* a bar chart (just without spaces in between the bars).

Comment: LOL oh no! i am expecting same as you are but it wont work all the time .so please tell me how can i draw the same using histogram

Comment: I don't see your problem.

Comment: ok leave all the things ! please tell me  how to draw the histogram of the data which is in image (out[48]) ?

Comment: Well, your data is 2 dimensional. For a histogram you only need a 1D data. I really don't understand what you want to achieve. And what do you mean by `it wont work all the time`?